How to introduce my gtk cursor theme to Snap GTK-Common-Themes
I have this pack of cursors in pling https://www.pling.com/p/1660518/ but I would like to develop it as a theme for snap but I don't know how to publish it as a theme in snap since when I move my cursors available for downloads it goes into DMZ-White
